# Scroll to Block in RichTextBox (read only)

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

I'm trying to use `ComboxBox` as navigation through content of read only `RichTextBox`. Selected value in `ComboBox` contains `Tag` of appropriate `Block` in `RichTextBox.Document`.

```
myRichTextBox.ScrollToVerticalOffset(myBlock.ContentStart.GetCharacterRect(LogicalDirection.Backward).Top)
```

didn't work and neither did

```
myRichTextBox.BringIntoView(myBlock.ContentStart.GetCharacterRect(LogicalDirection.Forward))
```

Comment: Set the caretposition http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.caretposition(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Didn't work, probably cause of 'read only'.

Answer (score 0):

As always, trying to solve this for one hour and after posting here I found solution.
Hope someone find this helpful.

```
myRichTextBox.ScrollToVerticalOffset(
            myRichTextBox.VerticalOffset 
            + myBlock.ContentStart.GetCharacterRect(LogicalDirection.Backward).Top
            );
```